# Nlog ASP.Net Core with Elastic search target not working

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, nlog

NLog.Config elastic search target:

```
  <target name="elasticWrapper" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
          <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"
                  name="elastic"
                  connectionStringName="ElasticUrl"
                  index="logs-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}"
                  documentType="logevent"
                  includeAllProperties="true"
                  layout="${message}">       
          </target>
        </target>
```

The connectionstringname attribute for elastic search target is used to get information from appsettings.json

appsettings.json is shown below

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ElasticUrl": "http://XXXXXX-XXXXXX:9200"
  }
}
```

Program.cs file from .Net Core project as shown below

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

    NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nLog.config");
    foreach (var setting in config.GetChildren().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value))
    {
        LogManager.Configuration.Variables[setting.Key] = setting.Value;
    }
    var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();  
    var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                   
                      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                      .UseNLog()  
                      .Build();

        host.Run();     

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `ConnectionStrings:ElasticUrl` instead of just `ElasticUrl` ? Have you tried to place `ElasticUrl` directly in config-root, instead of putting it inside ConnectionStrings-scope ?

Comment: @RolfKristensen : Tried both the configurations but still the indexes are created on my localhost ES instance but not on remote machine ES instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working programmatically.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

    var logFactory = LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nLog.config");

    foreach (var setting in config.GetChildren().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value))
    {
        logFactory.Configuration.Variables[setting.Key] = setting.Value;
    }

    var target = logFactory.Configuration.FindTargetByName("elastic") as ElasticSearchTarget;
    target.Uri = config.GetConnectionString("ElasticUrl");

    NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nLog.config");
    var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();  
    var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                   
                      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                      .UseNLog()  
                      .Build();

        host.Run();     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing couple of things

1. Add file target to see if your config is recognized by Nlog.
2. Rename Nlog.config to nlog.config and mark file properties value to always copy to output directory.
3. Make sure you have added NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch nuget package to your project.

I personally use my app inside container. So I moved entire settings into code and set their values using environment variables which perfectly works for me.

Let me know if your problem still persists. I will provide code to configure nlog via code.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Sahadevan answer.

If you are using BufferingWrapper the findTargetByName needs to be a 2 step process.

```
 var target = logFactory.Configuration.FindTargetByName("elastic") as BufferingTargetWrapper;
 var esTarget = target.WrappedTarget as ElasticSearchTarget;
```

example config:

```
<target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="elastic"
        flushTimeout="5000">
  <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"
         includeAllProperties ="true">
  </target>
</target>
```